# My Categories and search block is not showing in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2.3.0

[image]I only change the name of categories in Magento 2.3.0 and after this changing my search block, add to cart and categories not will show in my website main page.

Comment: have you cleared the cache and indexed everything?

Comment: yes i have clear.

Comment: please share screenshot of admin category @osamaanwar

Comment: assign all category to default category it will be visible on main page @osamaanwar if still not solved let me know

Comment: i am add a Screenshot in with my question.

Comment: set the index:reindex

Comment: i have clear my cache and also reindex.

Comment: i have set index but problem not solve